# Turn off uglification for require.js third party code

Tags: requirejs

Here is my require.js configuration for the optimizer.

```
({
      appDir: 'app/'
    , baseUrl: 'js'
    , mainConfigFile: 'app/js/main.js'
    , dir: 'build/'
    , modules: [{ name: 'main' }]
})
```

I have a folder in my project that contains third party dependencies called bower_components

When I run the require.js optimizer it iterates though every .css and .js file in these third party dependencies and uglifies them.  The trouble is that I am already referring to the correct *.min.js file in my code.  This takes a long time and I want to exclude the entire folder form uglification, however, I still want to to combine the third party dependencies into a single file where appropriate.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To turn off uglifying the code, add this line to your Javascript build configuration file:

```
    optimize: "none",
```

From the example.build.js docs:

```
    //How to optimize all the JS files in the build output directory.
    //Right now only the following values
    //are supported:
    //- "uglify": (default) uses UglifyJS to minify the code.
    //- "uglify2": in version 2.1.2+. Uses UglifyJS2.
    //- "closure": uses Google's Closure Compiler in simple optimization
    //mode to minify the code. Only available if running the optimizer using
    //Java.
    //- "closure.keepLines": Same as closure option, but keeps line returns
    //in the minified files.
    //- "none": no minification will be done.
    optimize: "uglify",
```

Here's a link to an example of [all the build configuration options](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js).

Comment: won't this disable it for all my code?  I only want to disable it for third party dependencies.

Comment: Oh yeah it will, guess I missed that part. Have you [seen this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219113/requirejs-optimize-tool-exclude-folders)? Or maybe [this could help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522216/how-to-exclude-certain-requirejs-files-from-uglifying-optimizing).